# How to stop a specific domain from Glassfish within Community Server Connection VSCODE extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, glassfish, glassfish-5, community-server-connector

Working with **VSCode** and **GlassFish 5** via the **Community Server Connector** extension, I am trying to work with my own domain (*sfeaapp*), instead of the default domain (*domain1*).

To this goal, from a terminal I have successfully created my '*sfeaapp*' domain, with the **asadmin create-domain sfeaapp** command.

Also, from VSCode I have been able to customize the start, thanks to editing 2 lines in the JSON that appears when '**Edit Server**' is clicked, so that it starts gentently on my '*sfeaapp*' domain when I click the '**Start Server**' action:

```
   "args.override.boolean": "true",
   "args.program.override.string": "start-domain --verbose sfeaapp",
```

But, the problem is that, when I try to stop the server, with '**Stop Server**' option, I get the following message and it doesn't know which domain to stop:

```
The domains directory C:\Installed\glassfish5.0.1\glassfish\domains
contains multiple domains. Please specify a domain.
Available domains: domain1, sfeaapp
Command stop-domain failed.
```

Any help will be appreciatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of GlassFish connector supports variable `glassfish.domain` - in Edit Server, change it from `domain1` to `sfeaapp` and set `args.override.boolean` to `false`. The variable `glassfish.domain` will be respected in the default start and stop commands.

Alternatively, you can use args overrides as you did but you also need to change the value of `args.shutdown.program.override.string` to `stop-domain sfeaapp`